# When I went to this URL: http://localhost/webmodify/Shoppycart/add_to_cart/

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, cart

> I found this type of error:
> Type: ArgumentCountError
> Message: Too few arguments to function Shoppycart::add_to_cart(), 0
> passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\webmodify\system\core\CodeIgniter.php
> on line 533 and exactly 1 expected
>
> Filename:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\webmodify\application\controllers\Shoppycart.php
>
> Line Number: 18
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\webmodify\index.php   Line: 315   Function:
> require_once

Shoppycart.php

```
<?php 

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  
class Shoppycart extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Cart_model');
       

    }
    public function index(){
        redirect('test');
    }

    // Add an item to the cart
    public function add_to_cart($product_id) {

     
        // Fetch product details from the database using the $product_id
        $product = $this->Cart_model->get_product_by_id($product_id);

        if ($product) {
            // Prepare cart item data
            $cart_item = array(
                'id'      => $product->id,
                'qty'     => 1, // You can adjust the quantity as needed
                'price'   => $product->price,
                'name'    => $product->name,
                'options' => array('image' => $product->image_url)
            );
            

            // Add the item to the cart
            $this->cart->insert($cart_item);

            // Redirect to the cart page or a success message
            // redirect('Shoppycart/view_cart');
            // redirect(base_url()."Shoppycart/view_cart/(:any)");
            redirect('Shoppycart/view_cart');


        } else {
            // Handle the case when the product is not found
            echo "Product not found!";
        }
    }

    public function view_cart(){
        $this->load->view('product/cart_view');

    }
```

Cart_model.php

```
<?php
 
class Cart_model extends CI_Model {
    
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    // Create a new cart item
    public function get_product_by_id($product_id) {
  

    $this->db->where('id', $product_id);
        return $this->db->get('products')->row();
       
    
}
```

cart_view.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>

<body>


<?php echo form_open('Shoppycart/add_to_cart/'); ?>

<div class="w-full overflow-x-auto">
    <table class="min-w-full">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="py-2 px-4">QTY</th>
                <th class="py-2 px-4">Item Description</th>
                <th class="py-2 px-4 text-right">Item Price</th>
                <th class="py-2 px-4 text-right">Sub-Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php $i = 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>
                <?php echo form_hidden($i.'[rowid]', $items['rowid']); ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="py-2 px-4">
                        <?php echo form_input(array('name' => $i.'[qty]', 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5', 'class' => 'w-full px-2 py-1 border rounded')); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="py-2 px-4">
                       
                        <div>
                <img class="object-scale-down h-48 w-96" src="<?php echo base_url($items['options']['image']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $items['name']; ?>">
                      </div>

                        <?php if ($this->cart->has_options($items['rowid']) == TRUE): ?>
                            <p>
                                <?php foreach ($this->cart->product_options($items['rowid']) as $option_name => $option_value): ?>
                                    <strong><?php echo $option_name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $option_value; ?><br />
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="py-2 px-4 text-right"><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['price']); ?></td>
                    <td class="py-2 px-4 text-right">$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['subtotal']); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td class="py-2 px-4 text-right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td class="py-2 px-4 text-right">$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total()); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="text-center">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('Shoppycart/add_to_cart/' . $items['id']); ?>">Add to Cart</a>
    </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Shoppycart';
$route['Shoppycart/add_to_cart/(:num)'] = 'Shoppycart/add_to_cart/$1';
```

Retrieve and display cart items and also add an item to the cart

Comment: Is this happening after you click the "Add to cart" link? What does the URL in the browser look like after you click that link? What was in the `<a href` link - did you check the rendered HTML source code? Did it contain a valid URL with an ID? It's not clear what, if any, debugging you've done. All we have is some source code and an error message. There's not really even an explanation of what events led to the error - hence my question. See also [ask]

Comment: P.S. As an aside, why do you have `<?php echo form_open('Shoppycart/add_to_cart/'); ?>`? You don't seem to need or be using a form here, and I don't see anywhere that you closed the form either. This line is probably unnecessary.

Comment: When I went to this URL: http://localhost/webmodify/Shoppycart/add_to_cart/

I found this type of error:

 An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Shoppycart::add_to_cart(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\webmodify\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 533 and exactly 1 expected

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\webmodify\application\controllers\Shoppycart.php

Comment: Yes you've already told us that. It's not what I asked you. Read my comment again and try to address it specifically so we can help you more easily