# How can i be redirect in view_cart function page through of add_to_cart function in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, documentation, cart

**codeigniter3**
as you can see in the below PHP code I'm trying to redirect the view_cart function but I am struggling to add_to_cart function that I want When I go to the add_to_cart function should be redirected to the 'Shoppycart/view_cart' page but add_to_cart throwing me an error.

Shoppycart.php

```
    public function index(){
        $this->load-view('test');
    }
    public function add_to_cart($product_id) {

        $product = $this->Cart_model->get_product_by_id($product_id);

        if ($product) {
            
            $cart_item = array(
                'id'      => $product->id,
                'qty'     => 1, // You can adjust the quantity as needed
                'price'   => $product->price,
                'name'    => $product->name,
                'options' => array('image' => $product->image_url)
            );
            
            $this->cart->insert($cart_item);

            redirect('Shoppycart/view_cart');
        } else {
           
            echo "Product not found!";
        }
    }

    public function view_cart(){
        $this->load->view('product/cart_view');

    }
```

Cart_model.php

```
   public function get_product_by_id($product_id){
   
    $this->db->where('id', $product_id);
        return $this->db->get('products')->row();   
}
```

when I go to this URL http://localhost/webmodify/Shoppycart/add_to_cart/

I got an error message:

```
 Too few arguments to function Shoppycart::add_to_cart(), 0
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Shoppycart';
$route['Shoppycart/add_to_cart/(:num)'] = 'Shoppycart/add_to_cart/$1';
```

Retrieve and display cart items and also add an item to the cart

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html

Comment: You've already asked this twice, and already been told not to post duplicates, and told that you need ti respond to comments on the original post before anyone can help you. Why are you still wasting time re-posting? For anyone reading, go to [When I went to this URL: http://localhost/webmodify/Shoppycart/add\_to\_cart/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77244018/when-i-went-to-this-url-http-localhost-webmodify-shoppycart-add-to-cart) instead for the original

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the function, your parameter is required. If you don't want to pass a parameter, please make sure to declare it as null.

```
public function add_to_cart($product_id = '') 
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: @ADyson

It's alright if someone has posted again, especially if they are new. However, it's important to note that your tone comes across as overly aggressive, and people are here is not to tolerant of it. This might not be the most suitable environment for such interactions.

Comment: No sorry but it's not ok to post _exactly_ the same thing twice or more, regardless of your experience level. [Review the guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), if you please. It wastes everyone's time, including the OP's. This is the 2nd time the OP has done it, despite being warned, and they haven't responded to requests for clarification either. It's very frustrating after initially attempting to help. I'm sorry if you found my tone of comment unpleasant in some way, that was not the intention. I admit I do have a tendency to state the facts of the matter fairly directly.